# Create Data Table with JSON in Google Charts

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-visualization

I have a hardcoded JSON object that I'm passing to google.visualization.DataTable() to create the data table object, but something appears to be going wrong. I get a JS error caught in the visualization api: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function". Here is the JSON data:

```
var jsonData = {
    cols: [
        {id: 'date', label: 'Sample Date', type: 'date'},
        {id: 'countervalue', label: 'Counter Value', type: 'number'}
    ],

    rows: [
        {c: [ {v: Date(2014, 4, 30, 10, 30, 0)}, {v: 2457.0} ] },
        {c: [ {v: Date(2014, 4, 30, 10, 30, 15)}, {v: 2458.0} ] },
        {c: [ {v: Date(2014, 4, 30, 10, 30, 30)}, {v: 2459.0} ] },
        {c: [ {v: Date(2014, 4, 30, 10, 30, 45)}, {v: 2452.0} ] },
        {c: [ {v: Date(2014, 4, 30, 10, 31, 0)}, {v: 2451.0} ] },
        {c: [ {v: Date(2014, 4, 30, 10, 31, 15)}, {v: 2443.0} ] },
        {c: [ {v: Date(2014, 4, 30, 10, 31, 30)}, {v: 2444.0} ] }
    ]
};
```

And this is where is appears to be blowing up:

```
var data = google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
```

Here's a JSFiddle of the solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/jcaine04/3PJph/2/

Comment: FYI, [this is not a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/), this is a normal JavaScript object. Your question has *nothing* to do with JSON, so I would advice to update it accordingly.

Comment: This solution will eventually call a web service that returns JSON, but for testing purposes I'm hardcoding this value. So I'm not going to remove the JSON relevancy of this question.

EDIT: Here's a link of what I'm trying to recreate: https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews#javascriptliteral

Comment: I tried using google.visualization.DataTable(JSON.stringify(jsonData)) and I still get the same result.

Comment: Try using the 'NEW' constructor as mentioned below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code works fine, you just need to change:

```
var data = google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
```

To:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
```

Also, change in jsfiddle from onLoad to noWrap  , if not `drawChart()` will not execute. Lastly, when you fix that it will throw you google error of: Pie chart should have a first column of type string×

Comment: Thanks for the help. The PieChart was a copy/paste error and I'm actually using a LineChart. I still get a google error of undefined is not a function though. I updated the jsfiddle to show that: http://jsfiddle.net/jcaine04/3PJph/4/

Comment: @jcaine04 pretty similar reason as well! Change all your `v: Date(2014, 4, 30, 10, 30, 45)}` to `v: new Date(2014, 4, 30, 10, 30, 45)}` and it will work ;)

Comment: Using the JSON strings, you actually want the dates to be strings: `"Date(2014, 4, 30, 10, 30, 45)"` instead of `new Date(2014, 4, 30, 10, 30, 45)`, as Date objects are not valid JSON.

Comment: But this is OK for hardcoded values. I need to do it dynamically. Then what should I do for that? How to pass JSON to map chart of google?

Comment: @RohannG its not hardcoded, the json is dynamic, so the chart will change acording to your json. If you are generating the json from server side, just use as @asgallant said for dates: `"Date(2014, 4, 30, 10, 30, 45)"`